# Unit test the non-existence of a dom element

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

In my directive, I use `element.remove()` under specific conditions to remove an element from the DOM.

```
it('should remove the <img> tag', function() {

   //expect(element.find('img')) ??
});
```

How can I unit test this?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the length of the *found* collection.

```
expect(element.find('img').length).toEqual(0);
```

Alternately, you could ignore actual DOM manipulation which is not so easy to test and kind of relies on external functionality (in this case, jqLite) and spy on `element.remove()`, eg

```
spyOn(element, 'remove');

// do stuff

expect(element.remove).toHaveBeenCalled();
```